# Erro ao publicar aplicação no IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis

Estou publicando uma aplicação no IIS, e ao acessar a mesma recebo o seguinte erro:

> Erro HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   A página solicitada não pode ser acessada porque os dados de configuração relacionados à > página são inválidos.

Informações detalhadas do erro:

```
Módulo     IIS Web Core
Notificação    BeginRequest
Manipulador    Ainda não determinado
Código do erro     0x80070021
Erro de Configuração       Esta seção de configuração não pode ser usada nesse      caminho. Isso ocorre quando a seção está bloqueada em um nível pai. O bloqueio é por padrão (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), ou é definido explicitamente por uma marca de local com overrideMode="Deny" ou o allowOverride="false" herdado.
Arquivo de Configuração    \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal\views\web.config
URL solicitada     http://localhost:80/portal/Views/Autenticacao/Entrar
Caminho físico     C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal\Views\Autenticacao\Entrar
Método de logon    Ainda não determinado
Usuário de logon       Ainda não determinado
```

Origem da Configuração:

```
29:   <system.webServer>
30:     <handlers>
31:       <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
```

Esse erro eu recebo ao acessar http://localhost/aplicacao/Views/Home/Index

O estranho é que geralmente, ao publicar a aplicação, acessando o endereço: http://localhost/aplicacao funciona.

Desta vez, ao acessar esse endereço avisa apenas que:

> "O servidor Web está configurado para não listar o conteúdo deste diretório."

Lembrando que o IIS está instalado em uma máquina com Windows 8.1

Comment: Você conseguiria configurar esse servidor, instalar pacotes, realizar atualizações? A resposta que eu teria envolve isso.

Comment: Consigo sim, pois levantei esse servidor em meu ambiente de trabalho.
Esqueci de mencionar que o IIS está instalado em uma máquina com Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Execute a seguinte sequência de passos para verificar a configuração do seu servidor:

1. No seu Windows, vá em <kbd>Painel de Controle</kbd> > <kbd>Programas e Recursos</kbd> > <kbd>Ativar ou desativar Recursos do Windows</kbd>;
2. Localize o nó "Internet Information Services", ou então "Serviços de Informações para a Internet". Expanda o nó;
3. Localize o nó "World Wide Web Service", ou então "Serviço da World Wide Web". Expanda o nó;
4. Localize o nó "Recursos de Desenvolvimento de Aplicativos", ou então "Application Development Features". Expanda o nó;
5. Verifique se ASP.NET está marcado. Se não estiver, marque e clique em Ok.

Comment: Era exatamente isso. Obrigado.

Comment: Faltava o asp.net 4.8 aqui. Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Após consultar o site de suporte da Microsoft, link abaixo, verifiquei que umas das causas do erro apresentado ocorre porque o arquivo ApplicationHost.config, ou o arquivo Web.config, contém um elemento XML malformado.

https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/942055/http-error-500-19-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage

Analisei o arquivo Web.config, como este é o mesmo utilizado em outro servidor porém em outra versão do Windows, não constatei qualquer erro de configuração.

Identifiquei que o erro apresentado é decorrente da configuração do IIS; ocorre que, por padrão, algumas configurações do IIS vem desabilitadas.

Para alterar referidas configurações, abra o arquivo applicationHost.config, disponível em:

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

O valor da chave overrideModeDefault das seções handlers e modules devem ser alteradas de “Deny” para”Allow” :

Após aplicar os ajustes acima, o erro HTTP 500.19 — Internal Server Error foi corrigido

Answer (score 0):

Tudo que as vezes precisa é saber a forma correta de configurar o IIS para receber o ASPNET Core.

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1), além do runtime, é preciso configurar o IIS